# A/B testing on non-stationary populations

Tags: chi-squared-test, fishers-exact-test, ab-test

I am running A/B tests on a website. The daily engagement level of the users varies wildly, with a strong weekly seasonality. (Basically, users who are willing to use the software on Sundays are more serious about it.) After a one-month experiment, I collected the data, and I did a 2x2 Chi-squared test or an ABBA test on it. The improvement was not statistically significant. Now, I'm not satisfied with this answer, because my own statistical significance test disagrees with the Chi-squared and the ABBA. Here is my own statistical significance test: except for 5 days, on each day of the experiment, the experimental group had a higher success ratio than the control group. If this was a chance occurrence, it would have probability ${30 \choose \leq 5 }/2^{30} \approx 0.00016$.

Does this counterintuitive situation suggest that I made some mistake in the setup? If not, considering that I do have the time information for the data points, is there a way to exploit that to design a stronger significance test? One idea I've googled is to do some significance test for each daily cohort, and aggregate the daily P-values into a combined P-value using Fisher's method. But I never did that before, and I suspect there are gotchas. First of all, will this combined test be stronger than the original, simple aggregated test? Also, how to deal with the days when the evidence was contrary?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why would you choose not to use a linear model to do the same hypothesis test while including terms controlling for the seasonality in your sample?